# Clustering of an image sequence of a moving object

Tags: clustering, image-processing, signal-processing

I have a set of 100 images of a man moving on the street. I remove the background and try to cluster the man using dbscan in each image seperately. Instead of getting one cluster (for the man), I get more than one cluster, ofcourse in all the images, the moving man is clustered but there is noise as well but noise is not present in every image sequence. It appears randomly in some image sequences. Is there any method to solve such problem like using a priori information?